# Why impose open sets in the defintion of a manifold?

Tags: soft-question, manifolds

The definition of a topological manifold X specifies that the atlas must consist of open subsets of X.
It can be easily understood for a differential manifold since the transitions maps must have open subsets as domain and codomain in order to be able to talk about differentiability.
But why is so for a pure topological manifold ? Are there examples of a topological space endowed with an atlas whose domains are not open subsets, which does not fit into the intuitive idea of "gluing open balls together" ?

Comment: See this question and the answer there too: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3400029/usage-of-open-sets-in-the-definition-of-manifold?rq=1

Comment: Open sets are at the heart of the definition of a topology. How can we say a subset of one space is topologically equivalent to another without looking at their topologies?

Comment: @John Douma : I don't understand your point. Every subset of a topological space is endowed with the induced topology, it does not need to be open.

Comment: @huurd The topology is the collection of open sets.

Comment: Still I don't understand your point...

Answer (score 5):

I think you're misunderstanding something. An atlas is not a collection of open sets--it is a collection of local charts, ie homeomorphisms from open sets of your manifold to $\mathbb{R}^n.$ The reason you want these domains to be open is because open sets of your manifold are the ones which respect the topology.

Every topological-space would be a 0-dimensional manifold if you didn't require the sets to be open: Each singleton is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^0$, that makes your atlas. But the problem is that sets carry topological data, and the subspace topology of a set loses a lot of information in general--it's only when taking the subspace topology on open sets that you retain this topological information.

For instance, if you don't require openness, then $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a 1-dimensional manifold: For each $t\in\mathbb{R},$ the line $x=t$ in the plane is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R},$ and so you can use these lines and the obvious homeomorphisms as your atlas. But this doesn't respect the topology of $\mathbb{R}^2,$ as we're essentially treating it like a disjoint union of lines, when in $\mathbb{R}^2$ those lines 'see' each other.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for answering, this was quite obvious indeed. I knew what is  a chart, maybe I should have said  "atlas whose domains are not open sets". Here the main point is "it's only when taking the subspace topology on open sets that you retain this topological information". Now I see.

Comment: I come back to try and get more detailed arguments. Ok, I see the simple counter example that Michael Barz gave which shows that if one allows domains of charts being closed subsets, the intuitive notion of a manifols as "gluing open balls" is not preserved. I also understand that open subsets of a topological space are very special among topological subspaces because their open sets are just open sets of the whole space contained in it.

Comment: But remains the question : why do the open subsets are precisely the right subsets to allow as domains of charts in order to stick with the intuitive idea of a manifold (say a surface) as "gluing disks together" ?

Comment: @huurd The intuitive idea of a manifold is *not* gluing disks together. Gluing disks together is more analogous to a different notion of a CW complex. The idea of a manifold is a surface that *locally* looks like $\mathbb{R}^n.$ If we want to say that a surface locally looks like $\mathbb{R}^n,$ we need to know that it looks like $\mathbb{R}^n$ in a small neighborhood of any point.

Comment: In the notion of CW complexes this would be more closed disks, here I am talking of open disks.  But so why the intuitive notion of  (say) a surface has been chosen as "locally looking as the plane (or open disks, which comes to the same)" ? I mean, what is the heuristic here ?

Comment: @huurd I'm confused as to what you're asking.That's what the heuristic is: Locally looks like the plane. If you are an ant crawling on a surface, you should think it looks like a flat world (just as the Earth appears flat to us). I do not understand what you mean by your gluing open balls heuristic. If you can formalize it, great. If you cannot formalize it, I don't think you really have a heuristic.

Comment: No, I forgot now the "gluing balls together" since you pointed that it was not not the right notion to think of. I think I got it now, sorry for being confused. The primitive notion of a surface is that of a piece of rubber embedded in the space, and there are several ways of formalizing it (by means of equations, or a global parametrization when possible, or this very notion of topological manifold). Did Gauss ever thought of a surface in this way (locally similar as the plane) , or did it first come in Riemann's mind ?